# Idempotent elements in a C^*- algebra

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras, idempotents

[image]

While reading the proposition above, I'm stuck on understanding the three parts below.

1. Why is $z$ invertible?
2. How did we get $ez= ee^*e$?
3. Why is $(1-te+tp)$ invertible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Setting $a = (e^*-e)$,  we have that $a^*a\geq 0$,  so the spectrum of $a^*a$ is contained in $[0, \infty )$.  By the spectral
   mapping Theorem,  the spectrum of $1+a^*a$ is contained in
   $$
     1+[0, \infty ) = [1, \infty ).
     $$
   Since $0$ is not in the latter set,  it follows
   that $1+a^*a = 1+ (e-e^*)(e^*-e)$ is invertible.
2. This is easy.  Just multiply it out and use that $e^2=e$.
3. Observe that the element $n=e-p$ satisfies $n^2=0$ (use the relations $ep=p$,  and $pe=e$ to prove this).  So
   $$
     (1-tn)(1+tn) = 1-t^2n^2=1,
     $$
   whence
   $1-tn = 1-te+tp$ is invertible.